# ncurses novice - starting out with GNU C

Tags: c, gcc, animation, ncurses

**A simpler life**

I am returning to C to help reinvigorate my programming lobe. The last time I learned to program I was at college working with Turbo C on MSDOS.  Simple ASCII animations became an obsession once I found Borland's friendly `<conio.h>` one include away.  A lot of fun was had with the `gotoxy` and `textcolor` functions and it wasn't long before I was writing games like snake and pong.  It was a very rewarding way to learn a language, and each game pushed me further as I got more ambitious.

**ncurses**

I'd like start with similar game type projects.  Today though, I'm on a mac with a dusty linux machine in the corner. I could launch my beloved Turbo C in dosbox (an ubiquitous enough platform) but I want to learn C such that I can develop something that compiles naturally on any BSD or unix platform. I've been told that ncurses is the way forward but the GNU site has largely gone over my head. Back in the day I had my friendly `textmode` function and I was a`print` expression away from pong.  ncurses seems a lot more powerful.

**whoosh**

There must be many people who've been in this situation. I'm looking for a relevant tutorial or resource that will help me grapple with what ncurses is and how to work with it.  Any tips or similar stories would be of great interest too!

Comment: I've added to my answer, anwering your comment about ncurses windows.  Your question has changed substantially since I first answered, though - I don't know of an ncurses tutorial to recommend.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yup, `ncurses` is the library you're looking for.  As an example, here's the (n)curses equivalent of `gotoxy`:

> NAME
>
> move, wmove - move curses window cursor
>
> SYNOPSIS
>
> ```
>    #include <curses.h>
>
>    int move(int y, int x);
>    int wmove(WINDOW *win, int y, int x);
> ```
>
> DESCRIPTION
>
> These  routines  move the cursor associated with the window to
>   line y and column x.  This routine does not move the physical cursor
>   of the terminal until refresh is called.  The position specified is
>   relative to the upper left-hand corner of the window, which is (0,0).

**Addendum:**

In your comment you ask about curses windows - I don't think I can really improve upon what the ncurses man page says on this, so I'll just quote it:

> The  ncurses  library permits
>   manipulation of data structures,
>   called windows, which can be thought
>   of as two-dimensional arrays of
>   characters representing all or part of
>   a CRT screen.  A default window called
>   stdscr, which is the size of the
>   terminal screen,  is supplied.  Others
>   may be created with newwin.
>
> Note  that  curses  does not handle
>   overlapping windows, that's done by
>   the panel(3CURSES) library.  This
>   means that you can either use stdscr
>   or divide the screen into tiled
>   windows and not using stdscr at all. 
>   Mixing the two will result in 
>   unpredictable,  and undesired,
>   effects.
>
> Windows  are referred to by variables
>   declared as WINDOW *.  These data
>   structures are manipulated with
>   routines described here and elsewhere
>   in the ncurses manual pages.  Among
>   those, the most basic routines are
>   move and addch.  More general 
>   versions  of  these routines are
>   included with names beginning with w,
>   allowing the user to specify a window.
>   The routines not beginning with w
>   affect stdscr.
>
> After using routines to manipulate a
>   window, refresh is called, telling
>   curses to make the user's CRT screen
>   look like stdscr.  The characters  in 
>   a  window are actually of type chtype,
>   (character and attribute data) so that
>   other information about the character
>   may also be stored with each
>   character.

So, in summary, you can safely ignore the whole window thing and just use the stdscr window.

Comment: thanks, pointing out the window aspect helped me realize what the question 'should' be.  What is a window? Is it akin to a virtual page which is switched or streamed to the console? I am baffled by it.

Comment: Note: You might want to use `#include <ncurses.h>` to ensure that you are actually getting nurses, instead of an antiquated version of curses, but then again, one of the include files might be an alias. You never know.

Answer (score 2):

Well, on UNIX-like systems such as BSD and Linux you definitely want to use `ncurses` as the terminal emulators make your life really miserable if you don't.

You should probably write yourself a simple wrapper, containing the functionality you need and implement it differently for different OSes. On Windows there are a few [console functions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682073%28VS.85%29.aspx) you can use so that part won't be too hard.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a little program to get you started.

```
#include <curses.h>

int main(void) {
  int ch;

  /* The whole program needs error-checking */
  initscr();
  noecho();
  cbreak();
  printw("Hit Ctrl+C to exit ...\n\n");
  for (;;) {
    ch = getch();
    printw("Value of char: %d (%02x)\n", ch, ch);
  }
  endwin();
  return 0;
}
```

Remember to tell the linker to add the libcurses library.

```
gcc ... -lcurses
```

Comment: well played! A most helpful program!

Answer (score 1):

There is a library providing Turbo C like console IO to Linux: [TurboC](http://www.sandroid.org/TurboC/)
Also related: [CONIO for DevC++](http://conio.sourceforge.net/)